# Trouble iterating through _.each

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm new to backbone.js and underscore.js.  I have a registration and sign in form working with validation errors.
I'm capturing the errors when I submit a form that is not filled out.
I'm stuck when it comes to putting all the errors on the form. I only get the last error in the array for all the form elements. I researched and can't seem to find a solution.  Code snippet below.

This function iterates through array but only gives me last index in the array not all of
the error messages.  My console log shows all the error messages when I do console.log(error.message)
but does not show all of them on the form only the last one as I state.  What am I doing wrong.

Your help is appreciated
Thanking you in advance.
I will post full code one I get it working so it can help some one else. I;m using backbone 1.1.2

PDH

```
validate: function(attrs, options) {         
var errors = [];
ect...

}

showErrors: function(errors) {

_.each(errors, function (error) {
var controlGroup = this.$('.' + error.name);
controlGroup.addClass('errors');  //not sure if I need this
$("div.form-group").find('.help-inline').text(error.message);

}, this );
},
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of this

```
$("div.form-group").find('.help-inline').text(error.message);
```

use

```
$("div.form-group").find('.help-inline').append(error.message+"<br />");
```

In each loop you are overwriting the text that was already present. Hence only the last index would be present

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, the append works but now I get every error on each line when it should only be one error for each element in the array.

Comment: Please use <br /> tag like this.. $("div.form-group").find('.help-inline').append(error.message+"<br />");

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the error divs. Get appropriate error from the array. Set error as the text of the error div.

```
_.each($("div.form-group").find('.help-inline'), function(errorDiv, index){

 $(errorDiv).text(errors[index]);
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y1hxnut9/1/)**

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work for me errors is an object which holds all the information about the error

Comment: var errors = [];
          alert("Errors Being caught"); //error handling
          
            if (!attrs.email){ 
            errors.push({name: 'email', message: 'Please enter a valid email address.'});
            }                                                                     if(errors.length > 0) {        
            return errors.length > 0 ? errors : false;
         
            
             }

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my issue was, I can kick myself for not seeing the obvious.  The code I have is correct the issue is that I was over writing the class because all the classes had the same name. I had to make some changes in my
HTML code. Before I had all the class names the same such as form-group.  I changed the name to form-group email
for example and it cleared up several issues in my validation. Hope it saves someone else time
PDH

```
<div class="form-group email">
<label for="email2">email &nbsp;<span class="help-inline">
</span><input type="email" name="email"></label><br />             
</div>

showErrors: function(errors) {

 _.each(errors, function ( error, index) {

 var controlGroup = this.$('.' + error.name);
 controlGroup.addClass('errors');

 controlGroup.find('.help-inline').text(error.message);
 console.log(error.message);


}, this);
},
```